# Plivo ruby gem class conflicting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `gem plivo`.When I am including `plivo` library in my code, there are 2-3 class which are same which I am using and `plivo` using, so my class conflicting.

Is there any way to solve this in ruby?

Comment: We can help you better if you can post related code and error log, if any

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use namespace while including the plivo lib.

For Example:

```
module PlivoModule
    module Plivo
     #plivo code
    end
end
```

Use as: `PlivoModule::Plivo::RestAPI.new`